Caller does not have required permission to use project
When authenticating, I get the following error:
(gcloud.auth.application-default.login) [xx@gmail.com] 
does not have permission to access projects instance [xx:testIamPermissions] 
(or it may not exist): Caller does not have required permission to use project xx. 
Grant the caller the roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role, or a custom role 
with the serviceusage.services.use permission, by visiting 
https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=xx and then 
retry. 
Propagation of the new permission may take a few minutes. This command is 
authenticated as xx@gmail.com which is the active account specified by the [core/account] property.
Google developer console IAM admin
https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=xx

- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: googleapis.com
  metadata:
    consumer: projects/xx
    service: cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com
  reason: USER_PROJECT_DENIED


I have given my account the serviceUsageConsumer role.
I have associated my account with a service account (this is not the default service account)

I am new to GCP, any assistance will be greatly appreciated :)
Thank you!

You wrote that you're new to GCP. The errors you're receiving are uncommon and, for many common use-cases there should be no need to assign roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer so, I think you're doing something incorrectly. It's unclear from your question because it is not stated as a minimally-reproducible form only as a summary of the errors you received. If you're using Cloud Console, some screenshots would help. If you're using the CLI (gcloud), please copy-and-paste the specific commands and errors. What are you trying to do?

Don't worry overly about including references to the Project ID or Number, these aren't secrets and your Project's resources are only accessible to auth'd users. Do continue to be diligent about excluding secrets (token etc.) from your question.

Also, there are several questions with answers on "serviceUsage". Search first to understand better that IAM permission. In most cases, it is best to post exact details on what you are trying to do.
